# Position selectize option

Tags: angularjs, selectize.js

I am using angular-selectize , 
on the onInitialize method I am adding an empty option.

```
onInitialize: function(selectize) {
  selectize.addOption({id: '', name: 'None'});
}
```

I am also using a sortField value in order to sort the options

```
sortField: [{field: 'name',direction: 'asc'}],
```

Problem is that None option is been sorted too, I want to have that in the top of my options.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: It sucks, but I usually make those types of options with a special character to ensure they sort to the top. `'<None>'`

Comment: Simply adding a space character before your empty option text (`᠎ None`) is supposed to work. **Note:** Don't copy/paste from here, because in order to make it render in the comment I had inserted a mongolian vowel separator (it wouldn't start the code block).